# Python 3 Serial, send '-' character or white space

Tags: python, serial-port

Communicating to a embedded target, I would like to send the following string

```
fnnameTool -d1 -v
```

where `-d1` and `-v` are parameters to a program running on embedded host.

At the console I can see `fnnameTool` printed then garbage. I am attempting to use the following write line. Since I can send the first part of the line I have not included any other code.

```
serial.write(str("fnnameTool -d1 -v\n"))
```

Does Python 3 have the concept of character / line delay?
Am I missing a '-' character or white space escape?

Comment: no that should work fine ... serial can handle any char from `0x00 to 0xff`

Comment: possibly do a `serial.flush()`, but looks fine